# Add image to ToolBarItem

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I add an image to a tool bar item on Android? I've managed to do it for iOS by assigning a new view to the item's `CustomView` property.

I want text *and* an image. Not one of the other.

How does one access tool bar items on Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for use `ToolBarItem`.

```
 <ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="YourText" x:Name="YourName" Icon="image.png" Clicked="yourName_clicked"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
    ................... 
    ....................
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Are you using NavigationPage?

Answer (score -1):

You can check this [post](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-icons-in-navigation-toolbar/) to teach how to add an image to the toolbar.

But , in Toolbar.axml you can add your image

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/xamarin_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: This is adding image to tool bar. He's asking about adding image to ToolBarItem.